# Getting error message when pinging target machine through ssh with ansible inventory file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm learning Ansible. I created an inventory file to ping my target hosts through it.

Every time i am doing it I am getting the error message:

```
ansible [core 2.12.7]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ubuntu/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/ubuntu/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/ubuntu/vprofile/exercise1/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/ubuntu/vprofile/exercise1/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/ubuntu/vprofile/exercise1/inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/ubuntu/vprofile/exercise1/inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
<172.31.84.210> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: amazon
<172.31.84.210> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="vprofile-key.pem"' -o KbdInteractivi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="amazon"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ubuntu/.ansible/cp/715n && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.31.84.210> (255, b'', b'amazon@172.31.84.210: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\n')
web01 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: amazon@172.31.84.210: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
    "unreachable": true





I tried SSH with my host machine to target machine its working fine.
```

PS: Im using Ubuntu server as my host and target machine and I have put ansible_user=amazon

Please help me out.

Comment: Please don't paste code nor errors as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: Noted. Will keep that in mind the next time im going to post the question.
Can you help me out with this question of mine.

Comment: What is unclear with `amazon@172.31.84.210: Permission denied`? Which steps did you already take to understand this permission issue?

Comment: Are you sure the user is `amazon` ?

Comment: Im not sure about the user name as I have used Ubuntu instance on amazon so i dont think the username of that instance is amazon. Im still learning so i have used random name. Please let me know if i had any mistake.